# How to retrieve only one record in a OneToMany relationship?

Tags: jpa

I have two entities product and price. Each product should have only 1 active price.

Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // getter and setters
}
```

Price:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_price")
public class ProductPrice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Float price;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "productPrices", allowSetters = true)
    private Product product;

    // getter and setters
   }
```

I want to add a price field to my Product class so that I know the current price. The current price is basically the Price entry which has `active` set to `true`.

I know how to add a OneToMany relationship on the Product entity but this will give me all the prices. Is there any way to make it retrieve only the price which is "active" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve the single record based on your active column.
You need to use `@Where(clause = "active = 'true'")`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    @Where(clause = "active = 'true'")
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED) // this will give you object structure instead of list
    Set<ProductPrice> price;

    // getter and setters
}
```

Note: check which one is working for you from `@Where(clause = "active = 'true'")` or `@Where(clause = "active = true")`.

`@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)` this will give you object structure instead of a list.
like below.

```
{

}
```

if you don't want your single record return as list as below.

```
[{

}]
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to just have ```ProductPrice``` instead of ```Set<ProductPrice>``` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, for OneToMany relationship it should be collection. You can use List<ProductPrice> instead of set, but it should be a collection otherwise you will the an error.

Comment: 2024 update: `@Where` has been deprecated in favor of `@SQLRestriction`