# How can I map a OneToMany relationship to a OneToOne based on a limit clause?

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
data class Account(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid")
    var uuid: UUID,

    @Column(name = "email")
    val email: String,

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "created")
    val created: DateTime = DateTime.now(),

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "modified")
    val modified: DateTime = DateTime.now(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val connectionStates: List<AccountConnectionState> = mutableListOf(),
) {

    fun getCurrentConnectionState(): AccountConnectionState? {
        return connectionStates.maxByOrNull { it.modified }
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_connection_state")
data class AccountConnectionState(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    var id: Long? = null,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_uuid", nullable = false)
    val account: Account,

    @Column(name = "connection_status")
    val connectionStatus: String,

    @Column(name = "created")
    val created: DateTime = DateTime.now(),

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "modified")
    val modified: DateTime = DateTime.now(),
)
```

I would like to have a field on `Account` called `connectionState` that maps to the most recent `AccountConnectionState` based on the `modified` date column.

Above, I have done this with just a function that does based on the entire list from the `@OneToMany` relationship. Is there a way to map this to a single value in JPA without loading the entire list of `connectionStates` in a `@OneToOne` type of relationship?

In MySQL I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM account a
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM account_connection_state acs
    ORDER BY acs.modified DESC limit 1
) inn ON inn.account_uuid = a.uuid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Until you find better solution you could use something like [How to retrieve only one record in a OneToMany relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411735/how-to-retrieve-only-one-record-in-a-onetomany-relationship) .

Introduce a new field (e.g. `boolean active`) and then annotate `connectionStates` with `@SQLRestriction("active is true")` from `org.hibernate.annotations` - (this replaces the deprecated `@Where` from the linked question). The query will then contain `...and (xxx.latest is true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a nativ query in your Repository and return the result as a DTO or Entiry Object. On JPA mapping there is no way to map relations based on conditions.